# formatting in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formatting

In [excel-2010](/questions/tagged/excel-2010) can we format time column into text along with AM/PM information for corresponding time?

For example, COLUMN A has "daily" as text and column B has "6.00 PM " as value. Can we append these A & B Columns and display as "daily 6.00 PM" in single cell?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, try this formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(A1," ",TEXT(B1,"hh.mm AM/PM"))
```

The **CONCATENATE** function or '&' can be used to join values as text.

The **TEXT** function can be used to change values to text with a specific format.

Comment: everything fine but if  it contains AM and PM randomly means it is not possible to Append it accordingly using formula. so is there any alternative?